# How to run-app in Grails 4.0.3 app ignoring unavailable RabbitMQ

Tags: grails, rabbitmq, run-app

Everytime I try to run my grails app and RabbitMQ is unavailable, my application does not go up (start). It shows me the error and I have to fix it before running again.

But RabbitMQ is not essential, I would like it runs even if Rabbit MQ is unavailable.

Does anyone know a way for my application to show me only a WARN informing tha Rabbit is not available and go up regardless?

Thank you

Alfredo

```
java.net.ConnectException: Conexão recusada (Connection refused)
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.SocketFrameHandlerFactory.create(SocketFrameHandlerFactory.java:60)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:62)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.init(AutorecoveringConnection.java:156)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1095)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1054)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1012)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:1201)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory$newConnection$6.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionContextImpl.start(ConnectionContextImpl.groovy:132)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitManagedContext$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.start(ConnectionManagerImpl.groovy:194)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:351)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:64)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl$_start_closure4.doCall(ConnectionManagerImpl.groovy:179)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:263)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:421)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2296)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2281)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:2322)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$186.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:244)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:127)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.connection.ConnectionManagerImpl.start(ConnectionManagerImpl.groovy:177)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitManager$start$1.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContextImpl.startConnections(RabbitContextImpl.groovy:201)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContextImpl.start(RabbitContextImpl.groovy:82)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContext$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:115)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:119)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContextProxy.start(RabbitContextProxy.groovy:65)
        at com.budjb.rabbitmq.RabbitContext$start$0.call(Unknown Source)
```

Above, the response of the Grails 4.0.3 application if RabbitMQ is not available.

Below, my application.yml

```
grails:
    profile: rest-api
    codegen:
        defaultPackage: plataforma.msid.grails4
    gorm:
        autowire: true
        reactor:
            # Whether to translate GORM events into Reactor events
            # Disabled by default for performance reasons!
            events: false
info:
    app:
        name: '@info.app.name@'
        version: '@info.app.version@'
        grailsVersion: '@info.app.grailsVersion@'
spring:
    jmx:
        unique-names: true
    main:
        banner-mode: "off"
    groovy:
        template:
            check-template-location: false
    devtools:
        restart:
            additional-exclude:
                - '*.gsp'
                - '**/*.gsp'
                - '*.gson'
                - '**/*.gson'
                - 'logback.groovy'
                - '*.properties'
management:
    endpoints:
        enabled-by-default: true
    endpoint:
        health:
            show-details : always
---
grails:
    mime:
        disable:
            accept:
                header:
                    userAgents:
                        - Gecko
                        - WebKit
                        - Presto
                        - Trident
        types:
            json:
              - application/json
              - text/json   
            hal:
              - application/hal+json
              - application/hal+xml  
            xml:
              - text/xml
              - application/xml                                 
            atom: application/atom+xml
            css: text/css
            csv: text/csv
            js: text/javascript
            rss: application/rss+xml
            text: text/plain
            all: '*/*'            
    urlmapping:
        cache:
            maxsize: 1000
    controllers:
        defaultScope: singleton
    converters:
        encoding: UTF-8

---
hibernate:
    allow_update_outside_transaction: true
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: false
        use_query_cache: false
dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    logSql: true

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2017Dialect
            url: jdbc:sqlserver://ip:port;databaseName=BD_DOC_DIGITAL_CMB_PLATAFORMA;domain=DMZHLG
            username: usr
            password: 'dddd'
        cmbaut:
            gettingNewTokenUrl: 'https://hml.project/plataforma/cmbaut/api/v1/auth/refresh?grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token='
            gettingUserId: 'https://hml.project/plataforma/cmbaut/api/v1/parts/$partId/users/$cpf'
        rabbitmq:
            connections:
                - name: main                      
                  host: 192.168.xxx.xx
                  port: 5672
                  username: cmbid
                  password: xxxxx
                  virtualHost: "/plataforma"
        grails:
            plugin:
                springsecurity:
                    rest:
                        token:
                            storage:
                                jwt:
                                    secret: 'xxxx'
```

server:
servlet:
contextPath: /cmbid
port: 8081
max-http-header-size: 65536

Comment: you want to share your relevant structure & config

Comment: I will share my application.yml and tell you so.

Comment: @injecter. I have just inserted the configuration of my application.yml. Thank you if you could help.